# Custom variable in email

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I need to send order email in this  `shipping_arrival_time` how to send this

**observer.php**

```
class Bc_Deliverydate_Model_Observer
    {               

        public function checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method($observer)
        {
            if (Mage::getStoreConfig('deliverydate/deliverydate_general/on_which_page')==1){
                $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
     //           $quote =  $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        $quotes = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();

                $desiredArrivalDate = Mage::helper('deliverydate')->getFormatedDeliveryDateToSave($request->getPost('shipping_arrival_date', ''));
                if (isset($desiredArrivalDate) && !empty($desiredArrivalDate)){
                    $quotes->setShippingArrivalDate($desiredArrivalDate);
                    $quotes->setShippingArrivalComments($request->getPost('shipping_arrival_comments'));
                    $quotes->setShippingArrivalTime($request->getPost('shipping_arrival_time'));
                    $quotes->save();
                }
            }

            return $this;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php or or rewrite core files. better is to rewrite:

```
<?php
class Mage_Sales_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Abstract
{
  public function queueNewOrderEmail($forceMode = false)
  {
    $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();

    if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewOrderEmail($storeId)) {
        return $this;
    }

    // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
    $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
    $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);

    // Start store emulation process
    /** @var $appEmulation Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation */
    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

    try {
        // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
        $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
            ->setIsSecureMode(true);
        $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
        $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
        throw $exception;
    }

    // Stop store emulation process
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

    // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    }

    /** @var $mailer Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer */
    $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
    /** @var $emailInfo Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info */
    $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
    $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
        // Add bcc to customer email
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
        }
    }
    $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

    // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy'
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($email);
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }
    }

    // Set all required params and send emails
    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
        'order'        => $this,
        'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
        'shippingarrivaltime' => $this->getShippingArrivalTime()
    ));

    /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
    $emailQueue = Mage::getModel('core/email_queue');
    $emailQueue->setEntityId($this->getId())
        ->setEntityType(self::ENTITY)
        ->setEventType(self::EMAIL_EVENT_NAME_NEW_ORDER)
        ->setIsForceCheck(!$forceMode);

    $mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();

    $this->setEmailSent(true);
    $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

    return $this;
}
}
```

After that edit transaction email on below path in admin: System > Transnational Emails > New Order Email

and in template access variable like below

```
{{ var shippingarrivaltime}}
```

Comment: @kothari

I already update the file that you want please check.
If you don;t know that how to use above variable on template then please let me know

Answer (score 1):

For adding variable follow below step:

copy app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php or or rewrite core files.
better is to rewrite:

in queueNewOrderEmail() function you need set you variable in template params like other parameters you will find below snippet around at line no 1341:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
  'order'        =>  $this,
  'billing'      =>  $this->getBillingAddress(),
  'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
  'ShippingArrivalTime'  => "YOUR_VALUE FROM QUOTE"
));
```

After that edit transaction email on below path in admin:
System > Transnational Emails > New Order Email

and in template access variable like below

```
{{ var ShippingArrivalTime}}
```

I hope it will help you.

For saving it after selecting shipping method it should be like this.
And field name should be shipping_arrival_time in sales_flat_quote table.

```
class Bc_Deliverydate_Model_Observer
{               

    public function checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method($observer)
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('deliverydate/deliverydate_general/on_which_page')==1){
            $request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
            $quote =  $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            $quote->setShippingArrivalTime($request->getPost('shipping_arrival_time'));
            $quote->save();
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get 'ShippingArrivalTime'  => "YOUR_VALUE FROM QUOTE" value here

Comment: try this one.
$qouteojb = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
'ShippingArrivalTime' => "$qouteojb->getShippingArrivalTime()"

Comment: No luck i am not getting

Comment: i think you need to store arrival time in quote table and need to fetch it from quote table at the time of sending order email .
https://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/ 
link help you

Comment: I already tried no luck

Comment: please check and sales_flat_qoute table that there is field get added or not

Comment: Field is there but value stor null only

Comment: @Kothari
Please check i have updated the answer.

Comment: Hey afer this i can't get any mail

Comment: Can you please give me the full code order.php  'ShippingArrivalTime'  => "YOUR_VALUE FROM QUOTE"

Comment: @Kothari
Is ShippingArrivalTime attribute value getting store in sales_flat_quote table?

Comment: Actually i stored in sales_flat_order table

Comment: @okay i am providing you file

Comment: please give me that i got confusion fully

Comment: @Kothari 
Added new answer check it