# variable from CREDIT MEMO transactional email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional-mail

Credit Memo # `{{var creditmemo.increment_id}}` for Order # `{{var order.increment_id}}`

> Does someone know what file do these variables come from?

I need to add functions and variables but I don't know where they are located.

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to add custom variable to email template ?

Comment: Exactly. A variable and a function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this?

[Custom variable in email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/120943/custom-variable-in-email)

Makes sense with what you are trying to do.

The `$mailer->setTemplateParams` part is the part you need to look at.